# WP7 navigating to a different pivot

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I'm making a Windows Phone 7 app with a few different pivot pages. I want to execute some C# code in Visual Studio which moves to a different pivot to the one that's currently open.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the SelectedIndex property of the pivot control to move to the desired one.
For instance, if you want to go the the second pivot, you set SelectedIndex to 1.

Comment: this code doesn't work
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/MainPage.xaml?PivotMain.SelectedIndex = 2", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));

Comment: PivotMain.SelectedIndex = 2;
No need to use NavigationService, you're not navigating to another page.